# About libgdx, android and IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I thought it would be fun to try this out, and I have previous experience with android and Java, using intelliJ idea. But when I get my 'project' up and running, I don't know where to go from there, can someone show me how to make something show up somewhere on the screen?
This is what I have after setting it up:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new MyGdxGameTest(), config);
}
}
```

Where can I find tutorials on actual coding for this? Maybe I have got it all wrong somehow, I hope so, please tell me all you know about libgdx for android, or show me an example, if u have the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following and working through this youtube series by dermetfan.

[Java Game Development (LibGDX)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L)

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find tutorials on actual coding for this?

Official docs: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki
[Learning Libgdx Game Development](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Libgdx-Development-Andreas-Oehlke/dp/1782166041/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403002821&sr=8-1&keywords=libgdx)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tutorials out there, but it is possible, that they are hard to find.
Someone else asked a similar question and claimed, that most tutorials first let you "get your feet wet" and the "throw you 300 miles out in the sea".
I have wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296645/3182091) there, where i shared my knowledge, which is not verry much, but it seemed to help others, so i think you could try to read it.

As you aksed for "libgdx for android": The big advantage of libgdx is, that you can code 99% on desktop, for desktop and then make an android game out of it, with a few lines of code.
Of course while programming on the desktop you need to take care about the controlls, which on android are most times touchcontrolls, while on desktop you use a mouse (left mousebutton is like a "touch" on the cursors position) and the keyboard.

So try to read to the little "tutorial" i linked up there and also read the tutorials i postet in the other answer and if there are any more questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: @user3486059 Are there anymore open questions?

Comment: No, i've been watching the tutorial I got from 'Sound Conception' and it was great, so all is good :)

Comment: @user3486059 thats good :) Its a bit hard to find the right tutorials for libgdx, cause there are so many out there.