# Which Game Engine should I use

Tags: android, game-engine

Hey I am new to GameDevelopment and just took up an assignment to make a simple game for Android.

I am stuck with the very first step of choosing the GameEngine.

Its a very simple game with one actor which can be dragged left - right to skip the obstacles falling from the top.
I will need Collision detection, and may be {gravity}, on drag listeners also.

Please help me by suggesting which engine i should go for.

I prefer open source and need to end this game very very soon, so please suggest accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely vote for LibGDX as I mentioned in here: [How to create an Android 2D game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739555/how-to-create-an-android-2d-game/24739845#24739845)

LibGDX is very user-friendly, has a really good documentation with official wiki, and it's also multiplatform with desktop being one of them - no need for emulator or device to test the majority of the functionality and tiny changes, because it can run as a desktop app. Makes the development much faster.