# How to update SurfaceView from another Thread?

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have a thread where I will get some `Bitmap` one by one. Then whenever I get a new `Bitmap` I need to update my `SurfaceView` which in the main thread. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890900/using-a-custom-surfaceview-and-thread-for-android-game-programming-example and see if it helped

Comment: `activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { updateMySurfaceView(bitmap);}});`

Comment: @stealthjong if u can make it as an complete answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (bitmapIncoming()) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getNextBitmapAfterLongOperation();
            mActivityReference.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mActivityReference.updateSurfaceView(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the thread, make a public interface which defines a function which is called every time a bitmap is retrieved(from the internet i assume) like:

```
public interface ImageRetrievedListener{
  public void onImageReceived(Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

Implement this method inside your Activity where you are using the Surface View and in the onImageReceived callback, add the Bitmap received into the array of Bitmaps which the SurfaceView uses. Should work, if you still have any problems, do let me know.

//EDIT
Not sure if this is the best possible solution for this problem, but i'd solve it this way.

Comment: I doubt this will work, because the method is still called from the non-UI-thread

Comment: oh just use the runOnUiThread method to make it run on the UI thread.. also, we arent doing any UI related work here, so it shouldn't be a problem anyways.. do try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I know, however, the OP is doing UI-related work, he's updating his surfaceview with a bitmap.

Comment: exactly, we are just updating the array.. adding a new bitmap to it, in the background thread, the UI thread is using that array for UI drawing..

Comment: If you're updating an array from one thread, and reading it from another thread, you'll need to synchronize the access.

Comment: @fadden I'm working on ExtractMpegFramesTest.java from your site, may I ask you something about it?

Comment: @harry if you have a question about it, post it on stackoverflow; use appropriate tags (e.g. "android" and "mediacodec").

Comment: @fadden Can you have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417320/receive-frames-from-mediacodec-edit-and-show-on-the-glsurfaceview