# Receive frames from MediaCodec, edit and show on the glSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

What I'm working on is an application which can get frames then modify it (like move pixels in the frame). After that show the edited frames onto the screen with good speed, `glSurfaceView` will do that part I think. And `MediaCodec` will help getting the frames.

I'm trying a good example about `MediaCodec` like ExtractMpegFramesTest from http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/. Can I directly edit the received frames with GLES code and show it onto the screen without getting `Bitmap`?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "edit".  ExtractMpegFramesTest decodes to an external texture, renders the texture, and extracts the pixels; if what you want to do can be expressed as GLES operations on an external texture, it will be easy.  See for example "Texture from camera" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), which is using camera input rather than a video, but it's the same idea.  More complicated operations will require a more complicated solution.

Comment: @fadden Editing here is to make stereoscopic side by side become like parallax barrier. Is that possible?