# Top Android 2D Game Engines

Tags: java, android, android-studio, 2d

I am a seasoned iOS developer and started off with cocos2d for my 2D games and now have moved on to Sprite Kit as it's from Apple and will continue to be supported. Recently however, I have installed Android Studio and have begun to get the basics of java(android) programming down. So my question is, I now have all these games I developed for iOS and I want to port them to Android but I am wondering what 2D engine is the best to use for Android?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this not an eligible question?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I'm guessing this would be the reason : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: However, I still have a relevant post on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739555/how-to-create-an-android-2d-game/24739845#24739845 and I would use LibGDX because that is the best, in my opinion. Quick, well-documented, has a wiki and everything, not that difficult to set it up (you just need Gradle integration in ADT or just import to Android Studio and roll it). You do need a device to test because it's OpenGL 2.0+.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My apologies on the inappropriate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not made game on android but try using (suggested by a close friend)
`Unity` - as it supports Android amongst it's many deployment platforms (and it's free!!)

Comment: Thank you - I will check it out..I also heard of AndEngine, although it is undocumented..

Comment: http://unity3d.com/learn/documentation Documentation Link :)